# Is there a `faker.fake` method for python faker library?

Tags: python, faker, faker.js

I wasn't able to find a method in the [python faker library](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) similar to the javascript library method [faker.fake](https://github.com/faker-js/faker#fakerfake) for combining faker API methods using a mustache string format. If this does exist, can someone share references/docs on how to use this? If not, can someone help with a workaround?

Comment: There isn't a faker method, but you can use fstrings to get the job done `f'{fake.suffix_male()}{fake.name_male()}`

Comment: Check out the README and the Wiki tab on the github page https://github.com/joke2k/faker

Comment: @FabioCraigWimmerFlorey With the `faker.fake` in js library, I could specify a way for faker to generate values in a non-programmatic way (for ex: in a JSON file with `{"faker": { "fake": "{{datatype.uuid}}"}`) I could just pass the `faker.fake` object in JSON as a parameter to `faker.fake` method and get UUIDs. I don't see that happening with `fstrings` as they're still a programmatic way to specify templates.

Comment: @alexpdev If there's a particular section on the README or Wiki that addresses this question, can you please share a link to that section?